# eintegrity issue in nativescript

Tags: javascript, npm, nativescript

When i try to install Nativescript V6.8.0 or 6.8.x i get this Error :

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-bf7UQUo6n0c3Fxn5OXckpausCWjFg+qGLzN/LnaMsjF+9HYuSMbPPciWI6zPLu+KLnwjqwKzwPkozi/vxJYpvw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-bf7UQUo6n0c3Fxn5OXckpausCWjFg+qGLzN/LnaMsjF+9HYuSMbPPciWI6zPLu+KLnwjqwKzwPkozi/vxJYpvw== but got sha512-wyGWHP4AFW67EKazxHpKOCPu8cTK5mZSL5eXrLl0OFBoEY46wQLFgtVrPiBjrUp4rGg8fXnLUiRsoVSlgQAndw==. (15534 bytes)
```

can anybody help me please

Comment: It probably means that some file is modified as it dose not produce the same hash anymore.
learn more about integrity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: Hi @Endless , so do you have any idea about a solution for this issue ?